# Converting MathJax into pdf with wkhtmltopdf yields too small maths

Tags: python, pdf, wkhtmltopdf, mathjax, pdfkit

By using `pdfkit-python`based on `wkhtmltopdf`, I have managed to convert `MathJax`into pdf. `wkhtmltopdf` configuration options are the following:

```
options = {
    'quiet': '',
    'javascript-delay' : '5000',
    'page-size': 'A4',
    'margin-top': '0.75in',
    'margin-right': '0.75in',
    'margin-bottom': '0.75in',
    'margin-left': '0.75in',
    'disable-smart-shrinking': '',
    'dpi': '400',
}
```

This allows to obtain the `markdown` text that is large as expected, however maths do not scale accordingly.

Here a snapshot of the pdf obtained :

[image: mathJax to pdf yield tiny maths]

where maths appears definitely too small.

And here how it is rendered on the browser:

[image]

Any idea on how to tackle the problem, in other words obtain maths scaling with the `markdown` text in the pdf output, will be greatly appreciated.

Here below the MathJax config:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
    TeX: {extensions: ["mhchem.js"]},
    tex2jax: {
    inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']],
    displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ],
    processEscapes: true
    }
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" async
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
</script>
```

Comment: Try sharing a working minimal example that exhibits the problem.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger I've added more details, but I am not sure what I should say more. Let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution, by adding the following to `MathJax`configuration:

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
    CommonHTML: {
        minScaleAdjust: 100,
    }
});
```

thus increasing to 100% while default value is only 50 %. Reference is [here](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/v2.7-latest/options/output-processors/CommonHTML.html).

Comment: I didn't understand WHERE did you put that code. I am downloading HTML files from the internet, so that would be very cumbersome and complicated to modify the HTML file before passing it to wkhtmltopdf (but I am not using pdfkit, just the command line directly)

Comment: I've put those instructions on the main html file, through which all pdf conversions are done.