# wkhtmltopdf and MathJax: equations are rendered too small

Tags: render, wkhtmltopdf, mathjax, wkhtmltoimage, wkhtmltopdf-binary

I am trying to download the Feynman lectures using wkhtmltopdf. This is the command line that I use:

```
wkhtmltopdf.exe http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_44.html --javascript-delay 20000 --no-stop-slow-scripts ./out/I_44.pdf
```

However the MathJAX formula are rendered too small. Here is a picture:
[image]

How I can enlarge the rendered equations?

In [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44851460/converting-mathjax-into-pdf-with-wkhtmltopdf-yields-too-small-maths) the suggested solution (as I understand it) would be to add

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
CommonHTML: {
    minScaleAdjust: 100,
}
});
```

to the HTML.

But of course downloading the HTML file and modify it before passing it to wkhtmltopdf would be too cumbersome. I would prefer an easier solution if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using

```cmd
wkhtmltopdf.exe http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_44.html --run-script 'MathJax.Hub.Config({"HTML-CSS": {scale: 200}}); MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Rerender", MathJax.Hub], function () {window.status="finished"})' --window-status finished --no-stop-slow-scripts ./out/I_44.pdf
```

This will set the scaling factor for the math and re-render it at that size.  It also uses the `window.status` variable to synchronize the page capture with MathJax so that the capture occurs immediately after MathJax finishes (rather than waiting for an arbitrary delay).

Answer (score 0):

What works for me is close to the proposed approach above but with a different keyword.

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  "HTML-CSS": {minScaleAdjust: 100,},
  jax: ["input/TeX", "output/HTML-CSS",],
});
```

Reference is here: https://docs.mathjax.org/en/v2.7-latest/options/output-processors/HTML-CSS.html

But I guess (not tested) that you might be able to make the original proposal work if you replace the `output/HTML-CSS` with `output/CommonHTML`.